# Asynchronously Await a Particular Event in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have an existing API which runs a task that will take some time and then uses [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) to emit an event when the job is complete. For our purposes, we can assume it looks something like this.

```
const { EventEmitter } = require('events');

class Example extends EventEmitter {
  longRunningJob() {
    // Assume some long-running task is happening here...
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.emit('job_completed');
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Now, I'm writing an `async` function, and I want to perform several such tasks in sequence. A naive approach might be

```
const example = new Example();
console.log("Starting jobs...");
example.longRunningJob();
example.once('job_completed', () => {
  console.log("One");
  example.longRunningJob();
  example.once('job_completed', () => {
    console.log("Two");
    example.longRunningJob();
    example.once('job_completed', () => {
      console.log("Done :)");
    });
  });
});
```

But this suffers from the same readability problems that prompted us to invent `async` / `await`. So it makes sense to try to wrap this approach in some sort of `Promise`, which I've done as below.

```
const onEvent = function(obj, eventName) {
  let resolve;
  const promise = new Promise(function(res, rej) { resolve = res; });
  obj.once(eventName, function() { resolve(); });
  return promise;
};

const example = new Example();
console.log("Starting jobs...");
example.longRunningJob();
await onEvent(example, 'job_completed');
console.log("One");
example.longRunningJob();
await onEvent(example, 'job_completed');
console.log("Two");
example.longRunningJob();
await onEvent(example, 'job_completed');
console.log("Done :)");
```

We've fixed the "runaway indentation" problem, but this still doesn't quite satisfy me. `onEvent` is a messy mix of mutating variables and letting promise resolution functions escape scope that just feels brittle. Besides, this feels like a problem that isn't terribly uncommon: the desire to wait on a particular event. So my question is (a) is this functionality built-in in a more robust way to Node, and (b) if not, is there a more robust, less hacked together way to await a particular event?

Comment: you could do `const onEvent = (obj, eventName) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => obj.once(eventName, resolve));` - not sure if that's the "messy" part you're referirng to

Answer (score 0):

One simplification would be to return the Promise immediately instead of assigning to an outer `resolve` variable first:

```
const onEvent = (obj, eventName) => new Promise((resolve) => {
  obj.once(eventName, resolve);
};
```

You can also use a loop instead of writing out `onEvent` and `longRunningJob` many times:

```
const example = new Example();
console.log("Starting jobs...");
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  example.longRunningJob();
  await onEvent(example, 'job_completed');
  console.log(i);
}
console.log('done');
```

If at all possible, also consider changing `Example` to have a method which returns a Promise instead of using a callback:

```
const example = new Example();
console.log("Starting jobs...");
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  await example.queueJob();
  console.log(i);
}
console.log('done');
```

That would really be the best solution by far (have the method return a Promise that resolves when the job is done), but if it's a 3rd-party API it may not be possible to change its code.